# integer digit grouping in grails scaffolded views

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I have a default scaffolded view and in the list view, all my integer values are shown with digit grouping. (like 5,129)

I couldn't find a way to disable this behavior. I tried on both English and Turkish locale. I am not sure if it is used but the messages.properties file is all default values:

```
default.date.format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z
default.number.format=0
```

If I change the view and add g:formatNumber around the value such as

```
<g:formatNumber number="${fieldValue(bean: tagInstance, field: 'tag_id')}" type="number" groupingUsed="false" />
```

all that gets printed is 5 (for the number 5129)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eliminating the `fieldValue()` call fixed it.

```
${tagInstance.tag_id}
```

prints the number without any formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
default.number.format=#
```

Note that the `#` will cause a value of `0` to not display. If you want it to display, you'll probably want:

```
default.number.format=#0
```